# How do I solve this stochastic differential equation?

Tags: time-series, self-study, covariance, stochastic-processes, stationarity

So I have a second order stationary process $Y(t), \infty < t < \infty$ which has a continuous sample function, mean $\mu_Y = 1$ and covariance function $r_Y(t) = e^{-|t|}, -\infty < t < \infty$.

Then $X'(t) + X(t) = Y(t), -\infty < t < \infty$.

How do I find out the mean and covariance function of $X(t)$?

My Attempt:

$r_X(t)  = Cov(X(s), X(s+t)) \\= Cov(Y(s) - X'(s), Y(s+t) - X'(s+t)) 
\\= r_Y(t) - Cov(Y(s), X'(s+t)) - Cov(X'(s), Y(s+t)) + Cov(X'(s), X'(s+t))
$

I am having some trouble finding the last three terms i.e. cross covariance of $X'(t)$ and $Y(t)$ and covariance of $X'(t)$. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: It is practice for an upcoming exam.

Comment: $d/dt$ and $E[]$ are commutative. Does this help?

Comment: Substituting x prime won't help. approach 1. Go back to your sde for x and try integrating function.  Approach 2 you need to use ito isometry: an expression for covariance of X in terms of X'. .. Then you can substitute in definition of X'  to leave you with an ode for covariance of X.  But I am unfamiliar with this notation and its algebra.